# Disk usage treemap software for headless Linux

Tags: linux, disk-space-utilization

There are some programs which can display used disk space using a [treemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping), such as WinDirStat for Windows and KDirStat for KDE/Linux:

[image: KDirStat screenshot]

I'm looking for something similar, but for a headless Linux box. (E.g. run console data collection program on the server, then load the file in a graphical program in a GUI environment.)

Alternatively, what are other good ways to get a **structured** used disk space representation, with just SSH access?

Comment: this javascript parses du output:
http://code.google.com/p/treemaplib/source/browse/trunk/TreeMapJS/sample-du.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

NCurses Disk Usage (ncdu) is good for this.  See http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu for details.  It's available as a package for most popular distributions and lets you browse and find out where your disk space is used.  It uses text characters to display a bar-chart of directory usage so you get a semi-graphical interface, in a text only environment.

Comment: This one is awesome, highly recommended.

Comment: ncdu does not produce treemaps.

Comment: Almost a decade after this answer introduced me to ncdu, I created my own ncdu clone for btrfs: https://github.com/CyberShadow/btdu Thanks again!

Answer (score 11):

gt5 is very nice. It has a console interface and also creates html files you can view in your browser. It's in the repositories so you can just apt-get it.

Comment: nice one....wasn't aware of that package.

Comment: I've been using `gt5` for a while, but it has one considerable flaw: if you have a lot of files, `gt5` ironically requires a considerable amount of disk space (hundreds of megabytes) to generate the results.

Comment: The humor of that comment gets my upvote.

Answer (score 8):

I use `du -cks * | sort -rn | head -11`.

It shows the top ten directories by disk consumption.  I use it on /home and such all the time.

Comment: Brilliant! Nothing to install, does the job just fine, even if it requires navigating a little bit and run the command in different places to investigate where has all your free space gone.

Answer (score 6):

`xdiskusage` allows you to pipe the output of `du` into it for analysis. It's a great option.

Answer (score 3):

For headless servers [philesight](http://zevv.nl/play/code/philesight/) might be of great use.

(kludos for that gem go to http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-analyze-your-disk-usage-pattern-in-linux/)

Comment: This has been superceded by DUC https://duc.zevv.nl/ which is a order of magnitude faster.

Comment: https://duc.zevv.nl/ is unavailable...
[UPD] Ok, it uses http not https. "http://duc.zevv.nl/"

Answer (score 1):

You can run the same command if you connect on the server via ssh and use ssh X forwarding and an X server on your workstation. If you want from commandline:

```
df -k /*|sort -n
```

Comment: Yeah, that's obvious, but I don't want to install KDE on a server :) And I was looking for a nicer/more structured method than just sorting all files by size... edited question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of different softwares have been recommended here, and there are lots that let you analyze disk usage on a headless server without spinning up a display. However, the question does specifically ask for a treemap visualization, for which a solution hasn't yet been mentioned.

For that application you can use [Qdirstat](https://github.com/shundhammer/qdirstat) and its included `qdirstat-cache-writer` perl script. You run the perl script on your server, export the cache file, and view it on your local machine with Qdirstat. I believe Kdirstat has the same capability with `kdirstat-cache-writer`, so you could use either one.